# Why my Jquery AJAX fail executing some methods upon succeed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I made a form to insert new status to database. My scenario using jquery AJAX post method to do the job so the page don't need to be reloaded. Then after the method completed it will call another two ajax methods to refresh my application timeline (these two methods executes PHP script which is call Twitter API then refresh the timeline on my page). The update_status method is succeed but it fail to execute another two method. Any advice guys? I really appreciate your feedback.

this is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {  
        $("#update_status_btn").click(function() { 
           var user_id = $("#update_status #user_id").val(); 
           var status = $("#update_status #status").val();
           var dataString = 'user_id='+ user_id + '&status=' + status;

               update_status('profile/update_status', dataString);
           return false;
               });  
    }); 




});

function update_status(method_url, dataString)
{
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: method_url,
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function() {
              //the following methods won't executed :-(
                update_timeline('profile/get_user_timeline', '#user_timeline ul'); 
                update_timeline('profile/get_home_timeline', '#home_timeline ul');
          }
        });
}

function update_timeline(method_url, target)
{
        //get home timeline
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: method_url,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
            $(target).empty();
            for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                $(target).append('<li><article><img src="'+ result[i]['user']['profile_image_url'] +'"><a href="">'+ result[i]['user']['screen_name'] + '</a>'+ linkify(result[i]['text']) +'</li></article>');
            }
          }
        });
}


function linkify(data)
{
    var param = data.replace(/(^|\s)@(\w+)/g, '$1@<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
    var param2 = param.replace(/(^|\s)#(\w+)/g, '$1#<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
    return param2;      
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `#status`? You aren't `URIEncode`ing it, which could be a problem if certain characters are present.

Comment: Are you sure the URL is returning a status of 200?  If the ajax call doesn't think the call succeeded, the function defined in the success option isn't called.

Comment: @scott.korin Hmm.. I am quite new to this AJAX stuff, I didn't check it. But i check manually by looking into my database and it succeed inserting new row. Also it succeed update my twitter status. I put an alert in success callback function along with two others method. The alert shows up. It means the method was succeed right? but the others to methods seems not executed because my timeline doesn't refresh immediately. one thing, there's nothing wrong with `update_timeline` because so far it works (I put line of code to call it every 60 seconds in my script, and it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

i imagine that `result[i]['user']` in `update_timeline` is causing a problem -- probably a null value.  are you using a javascript debugger?  that should show you what the value of the result object is.

you can also define an error callback on your ajax methods, inspect the responseText of the jqXhr (jquery http xml request) object - it contains the response received from the server.  Obviously you are expecting a json object, but if a server error occurred, you may be receiving HTML which jquery doesn't know what to do with.

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'Post'
 url: method_url,
  data: dataString,
 cache: false,
 success: function() {},
 error: function (jqHxr, statusText) {
   //jqXhr.responseText holds the response sent from the server
                }
```

Comment: yes, i am using built in javascript debugger for chrome. actually, there's nothing wrong with `update_timeline` function, I've tried to call it directly after `$(document).ready` function. even it could update my timeline perfectly. I assumed there's something wrong with `update_status` function. Frankly speaking, I am new to this AJAX stuff, I've read the JQuery AJAX documentation. It said the `success:` callback method can retrieve an array of some function, but I don't know how to do it. The documentation doesn't include any  example regarding this issue. Do you have another suggestion?